# Align text in TextView with drawableTop

Tags: android, textview, drawable

I have this `TextView`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/silverCount"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:contentDescription="silver"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/silver"
    android:text="3" />
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

How can I center the `3` inside the `View` to be situated directly below the drawable I set with `android:drawableTop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `gravity` instead of `layout_gravity`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/silverCount"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:contentDescription="silver"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/silver"
    android:text="3" />
```

This will center the `3` inside the `TextView` to appear directly below the drawable like this:

[image]